# When to use which cosmological length description?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, distance

### Definitions

During a lecture I was introduced to several ways of expressing "length" in the context of cosmology. Explicitly, I was given the definitons ($a$: scale factor, $c$: speed of light, $\theta$: angular size of object in the sky, $L_{\rm phys}= a L_{\rm comoving}$, $F:$ Flux, $L:$ Luminosity)
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
\text{Comoving distance} & \chi &\displaystyle :=c\int_{a_0}^a \frac{da^\prime}{a^{\prime 2}H(a^\prime)}\\
\text{Cosmological angular diameter distance} & r(\chi)&\displaystyle  :=\frac{L_{\rm comoving}}{\theta}\\
\text{Physical angular diameter distance} & d_A&\displaystyle  := a\cdot r(\chi) = \frac{L_{\rm phys}}{\theta}\\
\text{Luminosity distance} & d_L & \displaystyle := \sqrt{\frac{4\pi F}{L}} = \frac{r(\chi)}{a}
\end{array}
$$

---

I'm missing context in these definitions. I don't really see their use nor do I understand the situations in which one would use, for example, $d_L$ over $d_A$.

### What I (think I) understand so far:

- Rearranging the definition of $d_A$ one finds $F=L/(4\pi d_A^2)$, which is how I would define the Flux, given a distance and the luminosity. So, I think I have at least some intuition behind this length and it seems convenient, since the Flux and Luminosity seem to be things that we can measure rather easily.
- The comoving distance stays fixed with respect to the expansion of the universe, while the real, physical distance would increase, as $L_{\rm phys} = a L_{\rm comoving}$ suggests.

---

### Questions:

- What is the idea behind these angular distances? Why are they useful/In which situations are they useful?
- In which situations is the Luminosity distance better suited as length measure than the angular diameter distances?